# Which sets have "large" chains of subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $S$ be a set. Let $\mathcal{P} (S)$ be the power set of $S.$ Let $T \subseteq \mathcal{P} (S)$ such that, for any two elements $Q$ and $R$ of $T, Q \subseteq R$ or $R \subseteq Q.$ Let $T$ be called a "chain" over $S.$ For $S$ with cardinality $0$ or $1,$ $T$ can have cardinality $1$ more than $S$, which, in these two cases, is equal to the cardinality of $\mathcal{P} (S).$ For countable $S,$ $T$ can have cardinality equal to that of $\mathcal{P} (S),$ since we can either interpret real numbers based on their binary representations as arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ or based on their Dedekind-cut representation as elements of a chain over $\mathbb{Q}.$  What are the possible cardinalities of $S$ such that, for a chain $T$ over $S,$ we can provide an injection from $\mathcal{P} (S)$ to $T?$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617374/can-sets-only-have-small-chains-of-subsets

Comment: Duplicate on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48231/given-a-cardinal-k-whats-the-biggest-dense-linear-order-with-a-dense-subset-of.

Comment: @EricWofsey What are "dense linear orders" and "dense subsets?"

Comment: If they are basically the "chains" that I defined, then this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @mathlander Yes, but questions on this site can't be marked as duplicates of questions on another site.